# ORA-29913-Error executing call, after migrating the database to Exadata

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a scheduler job which calls the procedure PR_DELETE_AUDIT_LOG. This code was working fine until the Oracle database was migrated to Exadata. Now whenever the job is executed we get the following errors as shown below.

```
ORA-29913: Error executing call
ORA-06512: in "ABC.PR_DELETE_AL_IMPORTLOG", AT LINE 49
ORA-06512: in "ABC.PR_DELETE_AL_IMPORTLOG", AT LINE 34
ORA-06512: in "ABC.PR_DELETE_AL_IMPORTLOG", AT LINE 34
```

The code for the job and the procedures are as follows.

**DELETE_AL_IMPORTLOG_JOB**

```
 BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
            job_name => 'ABC.DELETE_AL_IMPORTLOG_JOB',
            job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
            job_action => 'ABC.PR_DELETE_AL_IMPORTLOG',
            number_of_arguments => 0,
            start_date => NULL,
            repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYTIME=000000',
            end_date => NULL,
            enabled => FALSE,
            auto_drop => FALSE,
            comments => '');

         
     
 
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
             name => 'ABC.DELETE_AL_IMPORTLOG_JOB', 
             attribute => 'store_output', value => TRUE);
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
             name => 'ABC.DELETE_AL_IMPORTLOG_JOB', 
             attribute => 'logging_level', value => DBMS_SCHEDULER.LOGGING_OFF);
      
   
  
    
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable(
             name => 'ABC.DELETE_AL_IMPORTLOG_JOB');
END;
/
```

**PR_DELETE_AL_IMPORTLOG**

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE PROCEDURE "ABC"."PR_DELETE_AL_IMPORTLOG" 
AS 

   V_DELETION_DATE DATE;

   CURSOR CUR_OLD_FILES
   IS SELECT  FNAME 
      FROM    EXT_TAB_AL_IMPORTLOG_FILE_LIST
      WHERE   REGEXP_LIKE(FNAME,'AL_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{8}_\d{6}.txt')
      AND     TO_DATE(SUBSTR(FNAME, -19,15),'YYYYMMDD_HH24MISS') < V_DELETION_DATE;

BEGIN


   SELECT ADD_MONTHS
            ( TRUNC
                  ( SYSDATE
                  , DECODE( STARTZEITPUNKTABF
                        , 1 ,'DD'
                        , 2 ,'MM'
                        , 3 ,'Q'
                        , 4 ,'YY'
                        ,'DD'
                        )
                  )
            , DECODE(PERIODEABF,2,-DAUERABF,3,-DAUERABF*12,0)) - DECODE(PERIODEABF,1,DAUERABF,0)  
   INTO V_DELETION_DATE
   FROM LOESCHREGEL
   WHERE VERWENDUNGSZWECK_ID = 'CLALL';




   FOR REC_OLD_FILES IN CUR_OLD_FILES
   LOOP
      UTL_FILE.FREMOVE('ABC_AL_IMPORTLOG', REC_OLD_FILES.FNAME);
      dbms_output.put_line('Deleted file '||REC_OLD_FILES.FNAME);      
   END LOOP;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DECLARE
         V_PROCEDURE_NAME  VARCHAR2(30)  := $$PLSQL_UNIT;
         V_SUBJECT         VARCHAR2(255) := 'Error on DB procedure '||V_PROCEDURE_NAME||' on '||to_char(sysdate,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
         V_BODY            VARCHAR2(10000) := 'Hi all,'||chr(10)||chr(10)||'Procedure '||V_PROCEDURE_NAME||' returned the following error:'||chr(10)||SQLERRM;
      BEGIN
         SEND_MAIL ( 'GENERIC_DB_ERROR', V_SUBJECT,V_BODY);
         RAISE;
      END;  
END PR_DELETE_AL_IMPORTLOG;

/
```

DDL for Table EXT_TAB_AL_IMPORTLOG_FILE_LIST

```
  CREATE TABLE ABC.EXT_TAB_AL_IMPORTLOG_FILE_LIST 
   (    FNAME VARCHAR2(255 CHAR )
   ) 
   ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
    ( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
      DEFAULT DIRECTORY COLEIN_AUDITLOG
      ACCESS PARAMETERS
      ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE  

      PREPROCESSOR COLEIN_PROCESS:'AL_ImportLog_list_files.sh' 
              noLOGFILE
           nobadfile
           nodiscardfile
                 
         FIELDS TERMINATED BY WHITESPACE

                              )
      LOCATION
       ( 'lsOutput.log'
       )
    )
   REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED ;
```

where is the problem?

Comment: Line 34 is the cursor that queries table `EXT_TAB_AL_IMPORTLOG_FILE_LIST`. Maybe the file system or permissions changed due to the migration. Does the query work on its own? By the way, `dbms_utility.format_error_stack` might be more informative than `sqlerrm` in your email alert. (Do the emails include any more details about the error?)

Comment: i did the changes i got the error email as, Procedure PR_DELETE_AL_IMPORTLOG returned the following error:
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH callout
ORA-01850: hour must be between 0 and 23
ORA-06512: at "ABC.PR_DELETE_AL_IMPORTLOG", line 34

Comment: It sounds like a filename in `ext_tab_al_importlog_file_list` is not in the expected format.

Comment: i have update the ext_tab_al_importlog_file_list in the question,

Comment: `EXT_TAB_AL_IMPORTLOG_FILE_LIST` is an external table, and the error is happening when your program access to it. If the external table was defined with logfile, badfile and discard files, I would start for looking there

Comment: but lsOutput.log file is empty

Comment: The table definition doesn't matter here. One of the `fname` values does not match the expected date format, for example `'AL_12-34-56_20210830_999999.txt'` would match the regex pattern but fail the `to_date()`.

Comment: please could you suggest how to solve this. An example file name is AL_03-01-02_20210829_220230.txt

Comment: We can't tell you how to solve this, because it is clear that the problem comes from the data store in the external table. that's why when you do the query in the cursor you got `ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH` error, follow for the `to_date` conversion. Try to make a select over the external table using `VALIDATE_CONVERSION` to find which records are not matching the `to_date` transformation

Comment: What is your Oracle version? From 12.2 onwards you can use `to_date(substr(fname, -19, 15) default null on conversion error, 'YYYYMMDD_HH24MISS')`.

Comment: I am using oracle 19c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems to come from a value of `ext_tab_al_importlog_file_list.fname` that doesn't match the expected filename format. You might want to check the values to see which one is invalid and how it got there.

If you are using Oracle 12.2 or later, change the cursor to use an `on conversion error` clause:

```
select fname
from   ext_tab_al_importlog_file_list
where  regexp_like(fname, 'AL_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{8}_\d{6}.txt')
and    to_date(substr(fname, -19, 15) default null on conversion error, 'YYYYMMDD_HH24MISS') < v_deletion_date;
```

If not, you could try adding some more filters:

```
select fname
from   ext_tab_al_importlog_file_list
where  regexp_like(fname, 'AL_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{8}_\d{6}.txt')
and    to_date(substr(fname, -19, 15), 'YYYYMMDD_HH24MISS') < v_deletion_date
and    to_number(substr(fname,-10,2)) < 24
and    to_number(substr(fname,-8,2)) < 60
and    to_number(substr(fname,-6,2)) < 60;
```

This worked in my quick test, but combining filters with a conversion function is risky because there is no guarantee that Oracle will apply the filtering conditions in any particular order.

You can find the invalid values using either of the following:

```
select fname
from   ext_tab_al_importlog_file_list
where  regexp_like(fname, 'AL_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{8}_\d{6}.txt')
and    to_date(substr(fname, -19, 15) default null on conversion error, 'YYYYMMDD_HH24MISS') is null;
```

```
select fname
from   ext_tab_al_importlog_file_list
where  regexp_like(fname, 'AL_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{8}_\d{6}.txt')
and    (    to_number(substr(fname,-10,2)) >= 24
        or  to_number(substr(fname,-8,2)) >= 60
        or  to_number(substr(fname,-6,2)) >= 60 );
```

Comment: can you please tell why the previous code did not work. I am using the same oracle database version before exa data migration and the code seemed to be working at that time.

Comment: I suspect it's not related to the Exadata migration, and you were just unlucky to receive an incorrectly named file where a number greater than 23 appears where the hour is expected. If you query the table without the filter you should be able to spot the incorrect value.